# Finding corresponding string values of integers in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

When i do ReverseEngineering on APK files i usually encounter integer values in AndroidManifest.xml file. For example: `android:screenOrientation="1"`. In developer's perspective it is written in string (Example: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`). However somehow IDE replaces this string with integer values. My problem is how to exactly find corresponding string values of attributes in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Use AndroidStudio analysis apk

Comment: @Style-7 Using Android Studio's Profile or Debug APK options also shows integer values not string correspondings.